# Pointing domain name to azure traffic manager URL instead of directly to server IP

Tags: azure, dns, appdomain, cname, azure-traffic-manager

So I have a domain [badgag.com](https://badgag.com/) That points to an IP of the current server.

But I want it instead to point to [http://badgag.trafficmanager.net/](http://badgag.trafficmanager.net)

This DNS will route to the server with the lowest latency.

So I try to change mapping to

```
badgag.com -> badgag.trafficmanager.net -> closest web app -> IP
```

But I am not sure what A, cname etc records I need to change.

This is how it looks now:

```
A       @                   104.45.14.249           1 time
CNAME   autoconfig          @                       1 time  
CNAME   autoconfig.admin    @                       1 time  
CNAME   autodiscover        @                       1 time
CNAME   www                 @                       1 time
```

Thanks in advance :)

PS. 
I do not use www.badgag.com, I only want the [badgag.com](https://badgag.com/) to be used.

PSPS. After some research I found out that, pointing to a domain name like badgag.trafficmanager.com that does not have a unique public IP from my A record is not possible. In order to support "naked domains" or "root domain" I would need to use an ALIAS record to provide CNAME-like behavior on apex domains. But not sure exactly how. [More info on that here](https://dimuthublog.wordpress.com/2015/03/31/using-azure-traffic-manager-with-apexroot-domains/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to map your domain name to traffic manager, you should use `cname`.

Looks like this:

```
NAME                    TYPE   VALUE
--------------------------------------------------
bar.example.com.        CNAME  foo.example.com.
```