# How to configure CNAME for Application Gateway and Traffic Manager

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager, azure-application-gateway

I have this setup:
Traffic Manager Profile -> Application Gateway(piblic ip - xx.x.x.x) -> (based on host name redirect to backendpool) -> Redirect to webapp1 and webapp2.

How would I define a CNAME record in this case? I created an `A` name record for Public IP of App Gateway and `CNAME` record for Traffic manager profile. But I am not sure where to add the host name in azure portal to map to cname.

Can someone help?

Comment: Do you mean you want to map your own domain name to Azure traffic manager?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT Yes Jason.

Comment: You can use CNAME to map your own domain name to `xxx.trafficmanager.net`, please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map your domain name to traffic manager, you should use cname.

Looks like this:

```
NAME                    TYPE   VALUE
--------------------------------------------------
bar.example.com.        CNAME  foo.example.com.
```

Here a similar [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49446435/pointing-domain-name-to-azure-traffic-manager-url-instead-of-directly-to-server/49446902#49446902) about you, please refer to it.

You should add application gateway public IP address to Azure traffic manager endpoints, like this:

[image]

Comment: I have no issues in defining a `CNAME` for traffic manager, but after defining CNAME, how would it redirect to app gateway public ip? We don't have to map the hostname?

Comment: In Azure traffic manager, add traffic manager **endpoints** with application gateway public IP address.

Comment: Does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)